# php unique randomized numbers array with exception

Tags: php, random, except

I'm trying to generate a unique randomized array with exceptions,
i got this far:

```
function rand_except($min, $max,$no_numbers, $except) {
   //loop until you get a unique randomized array without except number

  $end=false;
  while (!$end){
     $numbers = rand_array($min, $max,$no_numbers);//get unique randomized array
     if(!in_array($except,$numbers)){
       $end=true;   
       break;
     }

   }
return $numbers;
}
```

but now i want the function to loop until the except parameter isn't in the array

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to add that functionality to the *rand\_array* function rather than calling it over and over again until it produces the output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it would be easier to solve this problem by updating the *rand_array* function (or writing a modified version of it) to generate the array without the *$except* value to start with.

If that is not an option, here is one possible solution that doesn't involve calling the *rand_array* function over and over again:

```
$numbers = rand_array($min, $max-1, $no_numbers);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
  if ($numbers[$i] >= $except) {
    $numbers[$i] += 1;
  }
}
```

You call the *rand_array* function but specify one less than the actual maximum number you want in the array. Then you loop over the results, and any value that is greater than or equal to the *$except* value, you increment by 1.

This is assuming that the *$except* value is in the range *$max* to *$max*. If not, you can just return `rand_array($min, $max, $no_numbers);` as is.